# Get a subarray from a numpy array based on index

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array vector, and I want to get a subset based on the indexes:

```
import numpy as np
input=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
index=np.array([0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1])
```

what is a pythonic way to get out output=[2,7,10]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
output = input[index.astype(np.bool)]
```

or

```
output = input[np.where(index)[0]]
```

Comment: `input[index == 1]` might also be worth mentioning.